# angular2 search using loopback

Tags: elasticsearch, typescript, angular, loopback

In my angular2 project i need to search data from the database using    loopback  how can i implement this using "wildcard" query in find(). Thanks in advance. Please help me.

Here is my query

```
this.model.find({
     "where": {
       "wildcard": {
         "name": "*a*"
        }
       }
  })
```

My result is an empty array.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in Mysql:

```
this.model.find({
   where:{
      name: "%a%"
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
this.model.find({
    where: {
        property: {
            regexp: <expression>
        }
    }
})
```

You can read more [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#regular-expressions)

Or you can use like/nlike you can reed about this [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#like-and-nlike)

Answer (score 0):

I recommends you use a [loopback-sdk-builder](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder) to generate api rest in your frontend proyect, and then consumes the find method. Simply like

```
getAll(): Observable<Model> {
  return this.myApiModel.find();
}
```